# Rails passing a validation test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model

```
class Vehicule < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_principal, :if =>:new_record?

  private
    def set_principal 
      self.principal ||= !!principal
    end 
end
```

If I test it, when I do `Vehicule.new.valid?` it always return false. Why did I had to add ̀`true` in the function to pass the test ?

```
  private
    def set_principal 
      self.principal ||= !!principal
      true
    end
```

Comment: Because your are not passing `principal` then it goes like `nil`, and if `!!nil => false`

Comment: So if a function returns false, the validation of the model fails ? I just wanted to set `false` to the `principal` attribut. Not to make the model impossible to create. If I want to be able to create a `vehicule` my function needs to return true ? This is the correct way ?

Comment: Yes `Vehicule.new.valid?` returns `false` model will not save.

Comment: goto `rails c` and try like this `v = Vehicule.new` and `v.save`, it should save, if doesnt then run `v.valid?` you will see, function returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, failed validations populate an errors object in your record instance. You can see the errors by running `model.errors.full_messages` which is always useful for debugging.

Secondly, test for the presence of a value using the `present?` method rather than using the awkward `!!` approach which returns false when called on nil. It would make your code much more clear but it's also useful because it recognizes "empty" objects as well. In other words `"".present? == false` and `[].present? == false` and `{}.present? == false` `nil.present? == false` and so on. There's also the `blank?` method which is the logical opposite of `present?`.

Finally, be mindful of your return value when using the `:before_validation` callback. Unlike other callbacks it will prevent validation if the function returns false.

Answer (score 1):

because not not nil => false.

In IRB:

```
foo = nil
!!foo  => false
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try `Vehicule.new(principal: 'WORKS').valid?`

```
def set_principal 
  self.principal ||= !!principal
end
```

It should pass.